# Why does a domain user get UnauthorizedAccessException with read-write permissions granted to "Everyone"?

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008, network-share, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Our application allows users to read-write files in a share at \\foo\bar$. An administrator granted "Everyone" read-write permissions on both the **Share Permissions** and **Security** tabs. When a domain user tries to write to that share, our application logs the following:

```
TYPE: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
MSG: Access to the path '\\foo\bar$\00074458_00076402.tif' is denied.
SOURCE: mscorlib

SITE: WinIOError
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at     Ceoimage.Basecamp.DocumentServers.DirectAccessServer._TryCommitQueueFile(IDocQueueFile file)
   at Ceoimage.Basecamp.DocumentServers.DirectAccessServer.SendQueuedFiles(Int32 queueId, Int32 userId, IDocQueueFile[] queueFiles)
   at Ceoimage.Basecamp.ScanDocuments.DataModule.CommitDocumentToQueue(QueuedDocumentModelWithCollections queuedDocument, IDocQueueFile[] files)
```

I do not have a domain account, so I cannot test the effective permissions of this user, but does "Everyone" extend to domain users? Do domain users have to authenticate to the server in addition to Active Directory if "Everyone" is considered a local principal? Is it considered a local principal?

Our application is a .NET WinForms app running on a Windows 7 client on a Windows domain, trying to access a file server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP 1. In case you can't tell, I am a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: The `Everyone` group contains all users in groups `Domain Users` and `Authenticated Users`. Are you sure that this specific user is a domain user? Maybe they run it as a local admin on that workstation, or something similar.

Comment: Your's is almost a complete answer, jim jupiter, but I don't know the answer to your follow-up question. Asking their admin now.

Comment: May be. I'm also thinking that share permissions may not be inherited to files. So you could ask them to check this out as well (there's a setting for that).

Comment: We cannot verify this because the file does not exist, i.e., it is going to be a new file. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking us to verify. You want me to check the permission on a specific file, right? That is what does not exist.

Comment: No, I meant that permissions inheritance to files is not enabled for that share. Pretty much what this guy says (it also gives a few instructions on how to check it): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/039f4743-6d04-4441-8d0c-b1555b360c46. This is more likely to happen than a non-domain account running the app. Don't worry that it's for 2003. It still applies.

Comment: Nope. Both the "Replace all child object permissions ..." and "Inherit from parent ..." checkboxes are checked. I did notice the DOMAIN\Users group has read access but does not deny write access on the NTFS directory. Other shares, to which DOMAIN\Users can write, grant both read and write to DOMAIN\Users as if Everyone does not extend to DOMAIN\Users.

Comment: Unable to tell from your post (you didn't include any code), but if your application is a web page, you must explicitly set the FileMode to Write when opening your file. Many overloads for opening a file in .Net do not require this. You must use one that does. - This may or may not apply, depending on the type of application, just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: The last paragraph of my question says (and has always said) "Our application is a .NET WinForms app ..." so it is not a web app. The stack trace shows System.IO.File.InternalCopy, which is a private helper to File.Copy, so no FileMode is used nor is it necessary.

Comment: Did you find the problem eventually?

Comment: Maybe you start the program from a network share? Than there are sometimes issues eith restricted rights for the .Net app.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a "Deny" ACL on the file that prevents the user from accessing the file?  A "Deny" will overrule any granted access for a user.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the tricky authorization..

I've had to deal with this issue for quite some time. Here's the cause of the issue: LDAP works in GUID. Administrators group will most certainly have a different guid than the one currently present within the domain.

This problem occurs because the machine became out of sync or because the files were just transfered from a previous machine onto a new build (different HDD).

There's a fix!

I would add a catch and within, I would take ownership of the files and reapply domain policy from the ground up.

I've done that recently, if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Pointers to a URL on how to "reapply domain policy" programmatically?

Comment: Ah, well, programmatically.. .NET would be fairly straightforward. 'foreach(files in directory.enumeratefiles(..)' I haven't had to do that personally, since I only had one pc to handle. Right click c: drive and obtain ownership and, propagate, assigne proper security settings. Check here [link](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/setting-the-owner-of-files-and-directories-in-c/). Here's how to obtain the link; requires a bit of read through [link](http://bit.ly/18NF7fX) @flipdoubt

Comment: Seems like that first link didn't work for some reason. [Find it here](http://goo.gl/XkxCf)